# What did "append" do to my parameter outside the function?

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

Given a simple example:

```py
def change(a,b=[]):
    a+=1
    b.append(1)
A = 1
B = []
```

guess what happens if we:

```py
change(A,B)
print(A, B)
```

> 2 [1]

The parameter B outside the function, is changed!

But why could that  `b.append(1)` affect the parameter outside the function?

Comment: This is a well-know problem - it's been asked thousand times - you can do a quick search on `Python mutable list as argument` ~

Comment: You could run the code via visual platform like pythontutor.com to see what is going on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Daniel Hao, you could find the detail explanation to the notorious problem [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/)

> you should:

```py
def append_to(element, to=None):
    if to is None:
        to = []
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

Comment: The code shown in the question doesn't actually use the default! It has the exact same behaviour without a default or a placeholder.

Comment: Correct what? You already have an answer that explains what is going on.

Comment: Aha, I thought you mean that there was an error in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are objects (just like everything else in python). When you pass the list in to the function, you're actually passing in a reference to a list instance (the same instance that is stored in `B`). `append` is a method of a list that appends an object to the list instance. Since both `B` and `b` are pointing to the same list instance, both update when only one does.